# How do I create specific tuples from a column of values?

Tags: python

I want to make a tuple that looks like this:

```
t = (
    ("Type:", "Security Server"),
    ("Type:", "Primary Domain Controller"),
    ("Operating System Service Pack", []),
    ("Operating System Hotfixes:",
     "Update for Microsoft Windows (KB4049065)",
     "Update for Microsoft Windows (KB4486129)"),
    ("Dell PC:", "Yes")
)
```

Through iteration, my program's current output looks like this:

```
Type:
Security Server
Type:
Primary Domain Controller
Operating System Service Pack:
Operating System Hotfixes:
Update for Microsoft Windows (KB4049065)
Update for Microsoft Windows (KB4486129)
Security Update for Microsoft Windows (KB4503537)
Dell PC:
Yes
```

The elements of the tuple therefore need to be broken on the last line before the next line that ends in a `:`. Additionally, note that "Operating System Service Pack" had no entry after it.

I'll be using this tuple to populate a dictionary, however if there is a Pythonic way of popping my iterated output directly to a dictionary then this would be preferred over the tuple.

Here is an approximation of what this would look like in a dataframe:

[image]

I have pulled this data from an HTML document using Beautiful soup, parsing the tables and stripping whitespace.  Here is a small snippet. I will need to grab only the pertinent information and get it into a dictionary. Here is a small sample.

```html
<td class="ParamColumn">
                            Type:
                          </td>
<td class="ValueColumn">Security Server</td>
<td class="ParamColumn">
                            Type:
                          </td>
<td class="ValueColumn">Primary Domain Controller</td>
<td class="ParamColumn">
                            Software Revision:
                          </td>
<td class="ValueColumn">3.8.0</td>
<td class="ParamColumn">
                            Operating System Name:
                          </td>
<td class="ValueColumn">Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Standard (64-bit)</td>
<td class="ParamColumn">
                            Operating System Build:
                          </td>
<td class="ValueColumn">10.0.14393</td>
<td class="ParamColumn">
                            Operating System Service Pack:
                          </td>
```

Comment: Can you show here the actual pandas dataframe?

Comment: If you don't have a dataframe, that's also fine. It will be much easier for us to help you if you can show the raw data that generated the output.

Comment: Edited to update to answer questions.